# How to check what is VIRT memory usage composed of? Huge value (253G) in VIRT htop column

Tags: kde, memory-usage, 15.10, kde5

After upgrading to `15.10` and KDE `5.4.2` some KDE-related processes sometimes have a huge `VIRT` value in `htop`, for example:[image]

`top` shows almost the same, `0,247t`. Is there any way to see what it's composed of? FYI: My root FS space usage is `249G` and my RAM size is `4G`.

Comment: Look at the list of open files (`lsof -c plasmashell`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, both unfortunately and luckily I cannot reproduce that state anymore (I tried clearing cache and other related files). Right now it's around 3G and even this value looks far greater than size of used files listed in `lsof`.

Comment: I have it again with `krunner` and `lsof` doesn't give anything suspicious. The biggest opened file is 37M libQt5WebKit and there are just ~500 lines in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check /proc/**(pid)**/maps for the verbose info about allocated vmem ranges in a process. The virtual file states address range and purpose of the chunk, such as stack, heap, mapped file, shared object etc.

Format is very easy to parse with a script.